# How to use a function to square the arguments passed to another function?

Tags: python, function

```
# Use the square_args() function to square the arguments passed to multiply().
def square_args(func):
  def inner(a, b):
    return func(a * 2, b * 2)
  return inner

#WRITE YOUR CODE HERE

def multiply(a, b):
  return a * b
  
multiply(3, 9)
```

I need to use these functions to get answer 729.

Comment: So, do you know what it means to `square` a number?

Comment: Are you aware of [decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators)?

Comment: You didn't use `square_args()` anywhere. Why? What you are trying to achieve

Comment: I posted an answer with the decorators

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:

```
def square_args(func):
    def inner(*args):
        args = [arg ** 2 if isinstance(arg, (int, float)) else arg for arg in args]
        return func(*args)
    return inner

@square_args
def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b
  
print(multiply(3, 9))
```

Your just need to put `@square_args` in front of the declaration of your function and every arguments that will be passed in will be squared.
`square_args` is a decorator.

Comment: Brilliant answer. I didn't know about decorators before. Now I know. Thanks

Comment: btw You should really give the OP a chance to respond to the comments first otherwise they have no learning opportunity.

Comment: Can you explain to me def inner(*arg). How a function can be defined inside another function. Also about args variable how it works

Comment: a function is like a variable, you can define one inside another function with the slite difference that it will be a local function wich mean that you can't call it outside of that function

Comment: `*args` variable is a list that stores every positional arguments that has been passed to the function, no matter how many they are

Comment: check here for more detailed explanations : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/args-and-kwargs

Comment: Thank you I didn't know about decorators and there was a mistake in that func(a**2, b**2)

Comment: @S-c-r-a-t-c-h-y I have dropped a question in the team. Check it.

Comment: The way `inner()` is written it will _remove_ any argument that aren't numeric — which generally speaking would not be undesirable when calling the decorated function.

Comment: @martineau it has to remove non-numerical arguments since you cannot square a string or a list for exemple, I don't understand what's wrong in your eyes

Comment: You can leave them in the arguments — just don't square them.